# Ipython in pydev interactive debugging console(eclipse)

Tags: pydev, ipython

I have ipython working in pydev when using the normal interactive console, however when entering debug mode the console reverts to the standard pydev console. If I close this console and re-open it, ipython returns and I can use it as normal. Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

-Eric

Answer (score 2):

Actually since PyDev version 3.0 you can attache a IPython console to a debug-session:
  http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html#full-debug-support-in-interactive-console

To enable that feature, go to `window` > `preferences` > `PyDev` > `Interactive Console` and check `'Connect console to Debug Session?'`.

Then only hassle is that you have to re-open a new IPython-console every time you re-launch the program in debug-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Eclipse itself can have multiple consoles open at the same time... if you want, you can create multiple console views and pin a different console to each view (if you don't pin the console, one console will be shown on top of the other and you'll have to do the switching from one to the other manually).

As it is now, the debug console is not the same as the interactive console (it's a simpler version because of issues with the eclipse integration, although there are plans to be able to attach an interactive console to a debug session).

So, what you described is what should really happen (not really a bug).